# Has vs Had after past tense Forget

Tags: grammaticality

In the following sentence:

> I almost forgot she **has/had** a little sister.

The sister in question is alive.

In such context, should I use **has** (as in still has a living sister) or **had** (as in a follow-up of the past tense of the word *forgot*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could go either way, provided you are clear what is going on.

there is a rule of sequence of tense.  But how strictly it is followed depends on the circumstances.

1. Narrative (fictional or historical) in the third person

> Inspector Cluseau almost forgot that she had a little sister.

Here the two states of affairs (Cluseau’s almost forgetting and her having a little sister are simultaneous, so the tense of the verb in the subordinate clause must ‘follow’ the tense of the main verb and be past.

Unless, that is, the reported action, which was **continuous**.

> Inspector Cluseau did not notice that her hand **was stealthily moving** toward the gun on the desk.

Oddly, in both these cases, Latin and ancient Greek operated differently.  The main verb set the scene.  Anything simultaneous with that established time would have been expressed in the **present**.

> Paene oblitus sum illam sororem iuniorem **habere**

But the case in the question is not quite so simple.  It could refer to: a past occasion when the speaker almost forgot; or a present such situation.  Moreover, it could refer to a present occasion in which what the speaker had almost forgotten that she (now no longer living) had a little sister, In that case, it has to be:

> I almost forgot she **had** a little sister.

But if we are talking about a casual conversation about a (still living) person and her (still living) little sister, you can let the verb in the subordinate clause go either way.  It can ‘follow’ the tense of the main verb:

> I almost forgot she **had** a little sister.

Or it can follow the ‘simultaneity’ rule and preserve the present.

> I almost forgot she has a little sister.

Even this rather complicated answer avoids the full complexity of what we can and cannot do.  But I hope this is a.start.